# VueJS: How can I access prop defaults from outside the component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Basically, I'm looking to access prop defaults (value and type) from outside the component.

As background, I'm trying to create a form automagically based on the component selected. And I'd like the form to use the components default prop values, but I can't figure out how to access these from the vue instance of the prop (or through $props either). A workaround for me is to use the current value from $props, but this doesn't let me see the type value declared there. Thanks!

Comment: have u tried anything ? plz help us what u have done so far